# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing var from protocol

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a `protocol` that defines a `property` and a `class` that implements this `protocol`. When I try to get this property from variable defined as this class it works fine, but when I try to get it from variable defined as this protocol, I get below error.

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

```
internal protocol AugmentedRealityViewDisplayingOnSceneKit where Self: AugmentedRealityView {
    var currentCameraPosition: SCNVector3 { get }    
}

open class AugmentedRealityViewARKit: AugmentedRealityView {
}
extension AugmentedRealityViewARKit: AugmentedRealityViewDisplayingOnSceneKit {

    var currentCameraPosition: SCNVector3 {
        return sceneView.pointOfView?.position ?? .zero
    }
}
```

Now this fails:

```
let arView = augmentedRealityView as! AugmentedRealityViewDisplayingOnSceneKit
var cameraPositionAtNodeLevel = arView.currentCameraPosition
```

While this works fine:

```
let arView = augmentedRealityView as! AugmentedRealityViewARKit
var cameraPositionAtNodeLevel = arView.currentCameraPosition
```

`augmentedRealityView` is a reference to `AugmentedRealityView` object. How to fix this? Why does it fail?

Comment: This is [a known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6816) – Swift doesn't currently fully support being able to use `where Self : SomeClass` constraints on a protocol declaration like that. In fact, in the latest snapshots, this will crash the compiler.

Comment: This helped - I removed `where` from protocol (and actually moved it to protocol extension where default implementation was made), and now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: No worries! Should we go ahead and close as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46236315/2976878? [I added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878) there explaining that this isn't something that's fully supported (and used a similar example to yours in order to showcase some of the rough edges around it).

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day! I didn't thought Swift could be so strange! It works perfectly

Comment: This saved me, I was wondering for a while why I couldn't access an IBOutlet from protocol implementation..