# Error "Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'" - where is the `AnyObject`?

Tags: swift

I found a strange Swift compiler message while developing (I'm using **Swift 4.1**):

```swift
protocol Foo: class where Self: NSObject { // (1)
    // Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'
}
```

What is happening here?

**First, this is not redundant.** When I write

```swift
protocol Foo: class { } // (2)
```

I have a protocol that any object could potentially conform to, even objects that don't derive from `NSObject`. But I can create weak references: `weak var f: Foo?` is okay.

On the other hand, when I write

```swift
protocol Foo where Self: NSObject { } // (3)
```

I have a protocol where I cannot produce weak references: `weak var f: Foo?` is a compile time error.

**Second, where does the `AnyObject` come from?** I'm asking for `NSObject`. The `NSObject` is respected though: I cannot declare a `class MyFoo: Foo { }` because it rightly complains that it must inherit from `NSObject`?

**Is this a bug in Swift? Or am I missing something?** If it is a bug: is it a bug because snippet (3) does not let me take weak references? Or because of the compiler warning? Or both? And if I am missing something: what is it?

Comment: Constraining a protocol to a given class isn’t something that Swift fully supports yet (really it should reject the `where Self: NSObject` constraint until it does), compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878

Comment: @Hamish In Xcode 10b1 it seems to now work exactly as expected, but I haven't been able to find an announcement about this being added. Have you seen anything about it on swift-evo?

Comment: @RobNapier: I'm a bit frustrated about the current state of Swift generics. I should probably stop asking questions on SO about this, and re-evaluate this stuff in 2020, after Swift 5 is out. Right now, each time I'm trying to do something generic with Swift, I fail miserably. I don't have this problem with Haskell, or with Objective C, or even C++. In these other languages, whenever you combine types according to the rules of the language, it more or less behaves as expected. Allegedly, we'll get conditional conformances with Swift 4.2; finally. Meanwhile, I'll stick to non-generic code.

Comment: I've found that about 70% of questions I get about Swift generics involve code that was generic for generic's sake rather than an immediate need of the project. Definitely focusing on the problem at hand rather than trying to make things as generic as possible from the start is the best path for Swift today (I think it's true for Haskell, too, which people tend to genericize too quickly, but it's *especially* true in Swift). I think Swift types are pretty solid and full featured compared to Haskell 98 (8 years after Haskell 1.0 vs 4 years of Swift). I agree that Swift 5 is a good milestone.

Comment: @RobNapier: I understand your concern. I happen to program without generics 90% of the time. And before trying to use generics I think three times if there is any other way, at least in Swift. But then, occasionally, I try to do something generically: for example, I wanted to have a list of delegates, instead of just one delegate (should probably call them "observers"), and I didn't want to retain them all. So I decided to create a WeakArray.

Comment: ok; WeakArray isn't that hard to build in Swift. Though I prefer other observer patterns than multi-delegate. How did this bring you to NSObject?

Comment: @RobNapier: But appearently, WeakArray<BoardDelegate> does not compile, because BoardDelegate is just a class protocol. I had to hardcode WeakArray to use BoardDelegate. So now, my WeakArray is an array that can contain an arbitrary number of weak references to BoardDelegates. Because BoardDelegate is a class type, but T=BoardDelegate is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172993/discussion-between-rob-napier-and-michael).

Comment: @RobNapier Hmm, doesn't work for me in either Xcode 10b1 or a near-master build, with `protocol Foo where Self : NSObject {}`, `weak var f: Foo?` doesn't compile and nor does something like `func takesAFoo(_ foo: Foo) { print(foo.superclass as Any) }`. As far as I know, this is still something that hasn't been fully implemented yet on master.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to constrain a protocol to be subclasses of a specific class in Swift 4.1. You can inherit `Foo` from `NSObjectProtocol`, which probably matches your intent.

```
protocol Foo: NSObjectProtocol { 
    // ....
}
```

In Swift 4.2, what you've written is legal Swift and does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

From the Swift public API:

> `public typealias AnyObject 
>   /// The protocol to which all class types implicitly conform.`

So by declaring your protocol to conform to `class` it automatically conforms to `AnyObject`