# In Swift, what happens when a protocol is constrained to inherit from a class?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

First: the error code:

```
class AA { }

protocol Action where Self: AA {
    func method1()
    func method2()
}

extension Action {
    func method1() {
        print("method1")
    }
}

class List: AA, Action {
    func method2() {
        print("List method2")
    }
}

class Detail: AA, Action {
    func method2() {
        print("Detail method2")
    }
}

let controllers = [List(), Detail()] as [Any]
if let action = controllers.first as? Action {
    action.method2() //error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2).
}
```

then right code , everything work fine:

```
protocol Action {
    func method1()
    func method2()
}

extension Action where Self: AA {
    func method1() {
        print("method1")
    }
}
```

Question1: 
what happens when a protocol is constrained to inherit from a class?

Question2: 
What is the difference between the right code and the wrong one?

Comment: Constraining a protocol directly to a given class isn’t something that Swift fully supports yet (really it should reject the `where Self: AA` constraint on the protocol declaration until it does), compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878.

Answer (score 1):

A protocol *cannot* inherit from a class.

However, you can provide default implementations for protocol methods if the implementing class matches some conditions. The `where` clause defines such conditions.

This code:

```
extension Action where Self: AA {
    func method1() {
        print("method1")
    }
}
```

provides default implementation for `method1()` of protocol `Action` in class `AA`.

The following makes no sense:

```
protocol Action where Self: AA {
   func method1()
   func method2()
}
```

You cannot change the protocol for a specific class.

Comment: this is my question on https://forums.swift.org/t/what-happens-when-a-protocol-is-constrained-to-inherit-from-a-class/13696