# Swift protocol with "where Self" clause

Tags: swift, where-clause, swift-protocols

In addition to this syntax with a protocol extension:

```
protocol P {}
extension P where Self : UIView {}
```

... I discovered by accident that you can use the same where clause on the protocol itself:

```
protocol P where Self : UIView {}
```

Notice that this is *not* the same as a where clause constraining a generic protocol, and does *not* itself make P a generic protocol.

My experiments seem to show that only a colon can be used here, and the thing after the colon must be a class or a protocol (which may be generic).

I became curious: how did this escape my notice? So I went hunting for evidence of when it arose. In Swift 3.0, the former syntax is legal but *not* the latter. In Swift 3.3, both are legal. So the latter syntax must have been quietly introduced in something like Swift 3.2. I say "quietly" because I can't find anything about it in the release notes.

What is the second syntax for? Is it, as it appears, just a convenient way of making sure no other type can adopt this protocol? The Swift headers do not seem to make any use of it.

Comment: Being able to say `where Self : UIView` in a protocol declaration was accidental consequence of [SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) – the feature itself hasn't been fully implemented yet (really the compiler should have rejected the syntax until ready). It currently has lots of sharp edges around it, so I would steer clear of it for now – see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878.

Comment: @Hamish That comment is good enough to be the answer, imo

Comment: @Alexander Hmm, it does mostly duplicate the stuff I already say in the linked answer, but I guess it's more accessible as an answer to this question... yeah okay I'll write an answer :)

Comment: Possibly related topic in the Swift forum: [What happens when a protocol is constrained to inherit from a class?](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-happens-when-a-protocol-is-constrained-to-inherit-from-a-class/13696)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The ability to put superclass constraints on protocols declarations (that is, being able to define `protocol P where Self : C` where `C` is the type of a class) was a premature consequence of 
[SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md), and the syntax should have been rejected in Swift 4.x until the feature was implemented. Attempting to use this feature in Swift 4.x [can cause miscompilation and crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878), so I would avoid using it until Swift 5.

In Swift 5 (Xcode 10.2) the feature has [now been implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/17851). From [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2):

> Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that
>   subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:
>
> ```
> protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ }
> protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> Swift 4.2 accepted the second form, but it wasn’t fully implemented
>   and could sometimes crash at compile time or runtime. ([SR-5581](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5581))
>   (38077232)

This syntax places a superclass constraint on `MyView` which restricts conforming types to those inheriting from (or being) `UIView`. In addition, the usage of `MyView` is semantically equivalent to a class existential (e.g `UIView & MyView`) in that you can access both members of the class and requirements of the protocol on the value.

For example, expanding upon the release notes' example:

```
protocol MyView : UIView {
  var foo: Int { get }
}

class C : MyView {} // error: 'P' requires that 'C' inherit from 'UIView'

class CustomView : UIView, MyView {
  var foo: Int = 0
}

// ...

let myView: MyView = CustomView(frame: .zero)

// We can access both `UIView` members on a `MyView` value
print(myView.backgroundColor as Any)

// ... and `MyView` members as usual.
print(myView.foo)
```

Comment: `protocol P : UIView {}` I hope not!

Comment: @matt Yup: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/17816/files#diff-aa83dde62f0d33c0d5992adbdb17060aR207

Comment: IMO the change makes sense – protocol derivations (i.e `protocol P2 : P1`) should really be semantically equivalent to constraints on `Self`, i.e `protocol P2 where Self : P1`. So if you allow `protocol P2 where Self : SomeClass`, it seems logical to also allow `protocol P2 : SomeClass` (that being said, I do appreciate how it could be easily mistaken for inheritance).

Comment: Anyway to `protocol P where Self : C & Self: Decodable{}`?  **EDIT:** Nevermind. I can use typealias to combine C & Decodable and the constrain Self to that alias type...

Comment: @Honey In Swift 5 you would write `protocol P where Self : C, Self : Decodable {}` or `protocol P where Self : C & Decodable {}` or `protocol P : C, Decodable {}`. In Swift 4.x however, as discussed in my answer, such a construct isn't supported by the compiler.

Comment: I'm sorry What I intended to ask about was `extension` :) My initial comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Honey Ah okay, so `extension P where Self : C & Decodable {}`.