# Swift - Differences between inheriting protocol and constraining Self to protocol

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols, generic-constraints

I have a protocol `A`:

```
protocol A { }
```

What are the differences between implementing protocol `B` like this:

```
protocol B: A { }
```

versus implementing it like this:

```
protocol B where Self: A { }
```

?

What can I do with one that I can't do with the other? Where will I run into a problem with one that I could fix by switching it to the other?

Comment: The latter [will become illegal in Swift 5](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/17851/commits/eeb5c953aa4b22c00f031346a5445c1eecb6901c)

Comment: @Hamish is that a change from your https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913710/341994 ?

Comment: @matt Yup – constraints on a protocol's `Self` type in a where clause on its declaration were made illegal as a part of the work to implement superclass constrained protocols (which will be spelled `protocol P : SomeClass` in Swift 5).

Answer (score 4):

One difference is in how you conform to the protocol.

In the former case, a conformance to `B` implies a conformance to `A`.

```
struct BImpl: B {} // `A` is implied here
```

In the latter case, a conformance to `B` requires a conformance to `A`, but it doesn't implicitly create one:

```
struct BImpl: A, B {} // `A` is explicitly required here
```