# where Self: UIViewcontroller -> Compiler thinks I am dealing with a non-AnyObject instance

Tags: swift, protocols

This is my code

```
public protocol MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    var money: Int { get set }
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    func giveMoney() { // <-- ERROR: Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'self' is immutable
        money += 1
    }
}
```

This error shouldn't be thrown right? Every conforming instance of this protocol is a `UIViewController`, therefore a subclass of `AnyObject`. The compiler validates this, because when I add `: AnyObject` to my protocol, it compiles. BUT: Now I see an ugly error:

> Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'

This is the compiling code (so with the compiler warning):

```
public protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject where Self: UIViewController {
    var money: Int { get set }
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    func giveMoney() {
        money += 1
    }
}
```

Is this some bug? I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this syntax is not supported:

```
public protocol MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
```

It compiles, sort of, but [that fact is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913710/341994). The correct syntax is to attach the where condition to the extension:

```
public protocol MyProtocol  {
    var money: Int { get set }
}
public extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func giveMoney() { 
        money += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error just mark `giveMoney()` function as `mutating`.

```
public protocol MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    var money: Int { get set }
}

public extension MyProtocol {
    mutating func giveMoney() {
        money += 1
    }
}
```