# Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have this protocol:

```
protocol Container: class where Self: UIViewController {
    var containerView: UIView! { get }
    var currentChild: UIViewController? { get set }
    func remove(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func add(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func replaceCurrentViewController(with newChild: UIViewController)
}
```

the problem I am facing is that it shows the following warning

> Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'

this is because I am using both **class** & **where Self: UIViewController**, but I need both! the reason for that is in my protocol extension (found below), I use UIViewController methods, and if I delete **class**, my extension shows an error asking for adding **mutating**, which it should not have because its a class only protocol.

```
extension Container {
    func remove(child viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
        viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        viewController.removeFromParent()
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        currentChild = nil
    }

    func add(child viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        addChild(viewController)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        currentChild = viewController
    }

    func replaceCurrentViewController(with newChild: UIViewController) {
        if viewIfLoaded != nil, let currentChild = currentChild {
            if let parent = currentChild.parent, parent == self {
                remove(child: currentChild)
            }
            add(child: newChild)
        }
    }
}
```

so, is there a better solution? can I remove the warning?

Comment: What's wrong with declaring the methods as mutating?

Comment: The problem is that this protocol only applies to viewcontrollers & i use one of the methods inside didset of a var, i get an error asking me to make didset mutating & after doing that it shows me another error saying that mutating is only added to functions

Comment: Can you show the code in `didSet` then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where Self: UIViewcontroller -> Compiler thinks I am dealing with a non-AnyObject instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841954/where-self-uiviewcontroller-compiler-thinks-i-am-dealing-with-a-non-anyobjec)

Comment: Download the newest toolchain https://swift.org/download/ (Trunk Development (master)) and I think you do not need the extra constraint

Answer (score 3):

You should actually put the `where` clause in an `extension` and put `UIViewController` specific methods with default implementation inside that `extension` so that only `UIViewController` can access those methods.

```
protocol Container: class {
    var containerView: UIView! { get }
    var currentChild: UIViewController? { get set }
}

extension Container where Self: UIViewController {
    func remove(child viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
        viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        viewController.removeFromParent()
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        currentChild = nil
    }

    func add(child viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        addChild(viewController)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        currentChild = viewController
    }

    func replaceCurrentViewController(with newChild: UIViewController) {
        if viewIfLoaded != nil, let currentChild = currentChild {
            if let parent = currentChild.parent, parent == self {
                remove(child: currentChild)
            }
            add(child: newChild)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I about that, but I would like to constraint my protocol to only be implemented by view controllers, so other classes cannot implement this protocol. just to make it as correct as I can, to leverage static type where ever I can

Comment: @naif Yeah, that is an issue in Swift as mentioned in the answer by [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52842397/2395636). But you can achieve that by introducing an `associatedtype` if you really need to put that restriction.

Comment: I'd suggest in the above that you remove `remove()`, `add()`, and `replaceCurrentViewController()` from the protocol requirements and make them extension-only methods (rather than default implementations). The real protocol requirements are just the `containerView` and `currentChild`.

Comment: @naif: "I would like to constraint my protocol to only be implemented by view controllers, so other classes cannot implement this protocol." That misunderstands protocols, and does not in any way leverage static types. Protocols are descriptions of requirements, not demands for specific implementations. If the thing *must* be a `UIViewController`, then `Container` should be a subclass of `UIViewController`, not a protocol. (But protocol is probably fine here and there is no need that it be a view controller following Kamran's example.)

Answer (score 3):

In **swift 4** you can use

```
protocol Container where Self: UIViewController {
    var containerView: UIView! { get }
    var currentChild: UIViewController? { get set }
    func remove(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func add(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func replaceCurrentViewController(with newChild: UIViewController)
}
```

In **swift 5** you can use

```
protocol Container: UIViewController {
    var containerView: UIView! { get }
    var currentChild: UIViewController? { get set }
    func remove(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func add(child viewController: UIViewController)
    func replaceCurrentViewController(with newChild: UIViewController)
}
```