# If a Swift protocol is defined with a type constraint, why aren't the properties/methods of the type directly accessible?

Tags: swift, types, protocols, type-constraints

If I define a protocol with a type constraint:

`protocol Fooable where Self: UIView {}`

Why aren't the properties and methods of `UIView` directly accessible on anything conforming to `Fooable`?

For example:

```
func test(foo: Fooable) {
    foo.frame = .zero // doesn't compile because `frame` isn't part of `Fooable`
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler know that `Fooable` is now effectively `Fooable & UIView` because of the type constraint in the protocol signature?

This can obviously be achieved with:

`typealias Foo = UIView & Fooable // now use Foo as the function param's type`

but I'm moreso just curious why this is the case.

Comment: "*Shouldn't the compiler know that `Fooable` is now effectively `Fooable & UIView` because of the type constraint in the protocol signature?*" Yes, it should. However in Swift 4.x, superclass constrained protocols haven't been implemented yet – [the ability to write such constraints is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913710/2976878). In Swift 5 however, they are implemented and your code should work as expected.

Comment: With the latest toolchain your code will work. You can download it at the swift download page.

Answer (score 1):

- The constraint

  ```
  where Self: UIView {}
  ```

  is an information for the compiler that only `UIView` and its subclasses are allowed to adopt the protocol. The compiler throws an error at **compile time** if the rule is going to be broken.
- A protocol used as type responds only to the properties and functions declared in its body.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is moreso "why"? The protocol must also be the constraining type.

Comment: Actually a protocol **is** not a type.