# Protocol with where clause crash on accessing properties after casting

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, swift4.2

Casting an object to protocol (that is defined with where clause) and accessing properties causing crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Sample code that's crashing in Swift Playground.

```
protocol ProtocolA where Self: UIViewController {
    var id: Int { get set}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, ProtocolA {
    var id = 10
}

let vc:UIViewController = MyViewController()

if let protocolA = vc as? ProtocolA {
    print(protocolA.id) // Crash here EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

I have tried different things.

1. Remove where clause `where Self: UIViewController`, crash is gone.
2. No crash if object is accessed without casting. This works fine

   `let vc = MyViewController();
   print(vc.id)`
3. If mark protocol as Class-Only it works fine and doesn't crash but there is a warning

   > Rendant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'

[image]

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Swift protocol with “where Self” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913244/1187415) – protocol constraints of the form `Self: SomeClass` did not work before Swift 5.