# Why would a type constraint on my protocol make my method crash?

Tags: swift, crash, type-constraints

When adding a type constraint on my protocol my code crashes.

This is the code:

```
import Foundation

protocol MyTestProtocol where Self:NSObject {
    func myTestMethod()
}

class SomeClass: NSObject {
    var instanceVariable = "initial value"
}

extension SomeClass: MyTestProtocol {
    func myTestMethod() {
        instanceVariable = "overridden value" // <--The actual crashpoint
    }
}


let someClass = SomeClass()
let justTheProtocol = someClass as MyTestProtocol
someClass.myTestMethod()        // Works
justTheProtocol.myTestMethod()  // Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

When I remove the 'where Self:NSObject' part from the protocol, everything runs fine. Anyone an idea why this is? I thought type constraint are just constraints.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? [In Swift 4.x, superclass constrained protocols aren't properly implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913710/2976878). In Swift 5, your code compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Swift 4.2...  That would explain it then!  thanks

Comment: feel free to add you comment as an answer. Then I'll tag it as solved

Comment: I've marked the question as a duplicate, as I feel like my answer to the linked Q&A sufficiently answers your question. I can unmark as a duplicate and post a separate answer if you want, but I feel like I'd be duplicating points from my other answer.

Comment: The linked question states nothing about crashes. I don't think anyone would find it. But then again, maybe no-one would find this either.

Comment: Just added a sentence to my answer on the linked Q&A to mention crashes :)