# Swift constrained protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Recently, I saw the following Swift code, it compiles and works but I cannot relate to any OO topic I know of:

```
protocol SomeViewControllerDelegate: UIViewController {
  func someContractMethod()
}

extension SomeViewControllerDelegate {
  func someContract() {
     // provide default impl ...
  }
}

class SomeConcreteViewController: UIViewController, SomeViewControllerDelegate {
  func someCaller() {
    someContractMethod() // use the default impl provided in the extension.
  }
}
```

The developer told me that is so-called class-only protocol that doesn't seem right based on what I read from swift.org.  I did some study and the closest Swift topic of possible useful intention would be the so-called constrain protocol, https://forums.swift.org/t/constrained-protocol/14731 . However, the syntax is not the same.

Question:  Is

> protocol SomeViewControllerDelegate: UIViewController

the same as

> protocol SomeViewControllerDelegate where Self: UIViewController

If not, does it look like circulate/duplicate inheritance hierarchy that probably just some clever developer found a Swift compiler loophole. I personally can think of other traditional class/protocol hierarchy to achieve similar purpose but just wondering I missing any new concept?

I understand this is is a design/OO question, that could be situationally subjective, but please feel free express your OO opinions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913244/3141234

Comment: Thanks.  The link you provided above seem to answer my confusion: they are the same in Swift 5 and should be interpreted as constrained protocol.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. I'm closing this one as duplicate