# swift delegate variable is always nil

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I'm a relatively new developer and have used protocols/delegates fairly regularly but I am stuck on getting this one to implement properly.  I have a view within my view controller that is assigned a class for a StarRatingView.  I need to capture within the viewcontroller class the float value that the StarRatingView generates.

The star rating is working fine.  I'm just not able to set the delegate variable for some reason.

here's where I define the protocol and the delegate variable.

```
protocol StarRatingProtocol {
    func receiveStarRating(_ touchedStarRating: Float)
}



@IBDesignable
class StarRatingView: UIView {
    
    var delegate: StarRatingProtocol?  //THIS IS ALWAYS NIL NOT GETTING SET
```

Here's where I call the delegate function

```
    

fileprivate func touched(touch: UITouch, moveTouch: Bool) {
    
        guard !moveTouch || lastTouch == nil || lastTouch!.timeIntervalSince(Date()) < -0.1 else { return }
        print("processing touch")
        guard let hs = self.hstack else { return }
        let touchX = touch.location(in: hs).x
        let ratingFromTouch = 5*touchX/hs.frame.width
        var roundedRatingFromTouch: Float!
        switch starRounding {
        case .roundToHalfStar, .ceilToHalfStar, .floorToHalfStar:
            roundedRatingFromTouch = Float(round(2*ratingFromTouch)/2)
        case .roundToFullStar, .ceilToFullStar, .floorToFullStar:
            roundedRatingFromTouch = Float(round(ratingFromTouch))
        }
        self.rating = roundedRatingFromTouch
        lastTouch = Date()
        
        guard delegate != nil else {return} 
        
        delegate!.receiveStarRating(roundedRatingFromTouch)
}
```

This is my view controller class where I set the protocol and try to set the delegate value .  Should I be setting the delegate value somewhere other than viewdidload?

```
class LogController: UIViewController, StarRatingProtocol {
  

    @IBOutlet weak var starRatingView: StarRatingView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelStarRating: UILabel!
    
    let starRating = StarRatingView()
    var testRating: Float?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   
        starRating.delegate = self
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you say `let starRating = StarRatingView()`, that is a *new and different* StarRatingView that you are creating right now. That's not what you want; you want the StarRatingView that already exists in the interface. Presumably, if the outlet is hooked up properly, that would be `self.starRatingView`. That is the StarRatingView whose delegate you need to set.

Another (unrelated) problem is that the `delegate` needs to be `weak`. Otherwise there will be a retain cycle and a memory leak.

Comment: It worked!  Except for the weak var part.  When I tried setting weak var, I get error:  'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'StarRatingProtocol'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound.

Comment: I just did a little research and think I found that - add the 'class' to the protocol... I'll give this a try.  I'm afraid I am pretty ignorant on the various types of variable designations like weak and static and such.  I need to learn all that...

Comment: Adding `class` to the protocol is correct, although in modern Swift we are encouraged to add `AnyObject` instead of `class`. Either one will do fine.

Comment: @matt what is the difference between using AnyObject and class? I never heard of using AnyObject until you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @aheze yeah, they announced for Swift 5.2 or 5.3 (can't remember) that they wanted to change it, to bring this in line with other uses of protocol declaration along with adopting class limitation (like `protocol P : UIView`)

Comment: @matt thanks! Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913710/14351818) in case anyone else wants to read more about this

Comment: @aheze ah yes, my own question comes back to haunt me