# Strange protocol behaviour in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a protocol in my app:

```
public protocol ViewModel {}

public protocol ConfigurableView where Self: UIView {   
    func configure(with viewModel: ViewModel) 
}
```

Obviously, the purpose of this is to standardise my ViewModel approach.

When I apply the configure call in a cellForRowAt: method:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellType(for: indexPath).reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    let viewModel = process(item: item)

    (cell as? ConfigurableCell)?.configure(item:item)

    return cell

}
```

I see strange behaviour - essentially, the cell is of the correct type and has the properties I expect inside this method, but once it's passed into the configure method, all its custom properties (UILabels etc) are nil. It's like it made a copy of the cell without transferring over all the properties. It's a different pointer altogether once the code gets to the inside of the configure method.

What am I missing here? I've tried recreating this in a playground and I can't, which makes me suspect it's something weird about dequeuing cells.

Comment: Superclass constrained protocols aren't properly implemented yet, you shouldn't use them until they are properly implemented in Swift 5 – see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913244/2976878

Comment: (In the mean time you can usually achieve a similar effect using a class existential typealias as shown at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878)