# Swift 4.2, how to define a protocol for specific class or subclass

Tags: swift, protocols

I need a protocol which can be implemented by UIView only. So my code is like this:

```
// Code 1
protocol FooBar where Self: UIView {
    var name: String? { get set }
}
// The default implementation.
extension FooBar {
    var name: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.name) as? String
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.name, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
private struct AssociationKey {
    static var name = 0
}
```

But when I use it, I found that the variable must be declare with `var`.

```
// Code 2
class TestView: UIView, FooBar {
}

let testView = TestView()
testView.name = "TestView" // Xcode Error: Cannot assign to property: 'testView' is a 'let' constant
```

So I modify the protocol's definition, add AnyObject to the protocol:

```
// Code 3
protocol FooBar: AnyObject where Self: UIView {
    var name: String? { get set }
}
```

It works, but get a Xcode warning "Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'", which means the ": AnyObject" is Unnecessary.

I'm confused, without "AnyObject" the protocol can not work correctly, but add the "AnyObject", the Xcode tells me "Redundant"!

**Is it a Swift syntax error or a Xcode complier bug?**

**The following code is my Solution, but not perfect! So I want someone tell me a better way to do this. Thank you!**

```
// Code 4
protocol _FooBar: AnyObject { // define a base protocol at first
}
protocol FooBar: _FooBar where Self: UIView {
    var name: String? { get set }
}
// The default implementation.
extension FooBar {
    var name: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.name) as? String
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.name, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
private struct AssociationKey {
    static var name = 0
}


class TestView: UIView, FooBar {

}
let testView: FooBar = TestView()
testView.name = "Test"
```

Configuration: Xcode 10.0, Swift 4.2

Comment: In Code 2, `testView` is a `FooBar` and it behaves as `FooBar` would, and not a class `TestView`. If you want to be able to change some property of a `FooBar` define `testView` as a `var`. Plus, any properties declared in `TestView` that are not already in `FooBar` can't be accessed from `testView` as long as it is a `FooBar`. Better have `testView` as `TestView`.

Comment: In Swift 4.2, superclass constrained protocols aren't properly implemented yet – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913244/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878. In the latest master snapshot, your second example works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Is it means that is a feature of swift in future? @Hamish

Comment: @mlibai Correct – Swift 5 will the first version of Swift to properly support superclass constrained protocols.